# How to check how many bytes my application wrote and read from Disk?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I don't know if I didn't use the right words to search on web but I didn't find the solution to watch how much my application already read and wrote on disk.

Some one can help me with this ?

tks

### [Resolved]

If some one need the function sign.

```
type
  _IO_COUNTERS = record
    ReadOperationCount : LONGLONG;
    WriteOperationCount : LONGLONG;
    OtherOperationCount : LONGLONG;
    ReadTransferCount : LONGLONG;
    WriteTransferCount : LONGLONG;
    OtherTransferCount : LONGLONG;
  end;
  TIoCounters = _IO_COUNTERS;

  function GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess: THandle; var lpIoCounters: TIoCounters): BOOL; stdcall external kernel32;
```

Comment: Although not a programming question, this is something that many programmers need to know how to do, to fix their programs. So let's not close this one....

Comment: If programmers want to know then they can look on superuser where this belongs

Comment: SaCi, please re-phrase your question otherwise it'll get closed. I have withdrawn my off-topic answer about ProcessMonitor.

Comment: @David I think this is a perfectly valid profiling question! Programming is not only about typing code. When I use a compiler a debugger or a profiler I'm USING a software but that doesn't mean I'm not programming.

Comment: ok maybe you are right. Question would benefit from more detail though.

Comment: @David sure; after all he was looking for an api, so.. more programming than ever :)

Comment: I don't think he was specifically asking for an API as opposed to simply an answer of how to do it.

Comment: Non programming answer: check performance in windows tools like performance monitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want get this info programmatically you can use the [`GetProcessIoCounters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683218%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Another alternative is using the WMI , see the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class
 and check these properties (WriteOperationCount, WriteTransferCount, ReadTransferCount, ReadOperationCount).

Comment: I think is this that I was looking for. I'll check it after confirming I accept the answer. Tks